# Jenkins job - no options found under pipeline section

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I have started learning Jenkins recently.
I installed docker on a server which I created on AWS server and using docker I have installed Jenkins.
I wanted to test a `Hello pipeline stage` by creating new item, but when I go to the pipeline tab I cant see any options like `pipeline script` or `pipeline script from SCM` . I have installed `git plugin` and `pipeline plugin` also seems to be installed successfully. I am not able to continue my study further. I will be really thankful if someone can help me here.

Comment: Have you made sure that the item you made is of type 'Pipeline' and not for example 'Multibranch pipeline' or 'Freestyle project' ?

Comment: In reality `pipeline plugin` is not just one plugin but a bunch of 6 to 8 plugins. So you may want to install all the pipeline related stuff in your `available plugins` section and reboot jenkins for changes to take effect.

Comment: yes you were right .It started working after i installed all the pligin related to pipeline.Thank you so much  @mdabdullah  for your help !!!

Comment: Welcome @SunitaKunwar , please review the answer below and mark Accepted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality the `pipeline plugin` is not just one plugin but a bunch of 6 to 8 plugins. So you may want to install all the `pipeline` related items in your `available plugins` section of Manage Jenkins. Once this is done, a reboot of Jenkins is required for the changes to take effect. Here are some of them:

- https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin/
- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view/